# Automapper query for projecting an anonymous type onto a viewmodel

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, automapper

I have a very basic controller, which does a Linq to Entities query and I want to be able to project the results onto a viewmodel using AutoMapper - however I'm getting the error:

`cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.List<AnonymousType#1>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IList<tb.Models.Tour>'`:

**Controller:**

```
var tours2 = (from t in db.Tours
                     join d in db.TourDates on t.TourId equals d.TourId
                     join c in db.TourCategories on t.TourCategoryId equals c.TourCategoryId
                     where d.Date == dte && t.TourCategoryId == id
                     select new
                    {
                        Id = t.TourId,
                        TourName = t.TourName,
                        TourCategoryId = t.TourCategoryId,
                        Bookings = db.Bookings.Where(b => d.TourDateId == b.TourDateId).Count()                            
                    }).ToList();

        Mapper.CreateMap<IList<Tour>, IList<ToursAvail2VM>>();
        IList<ToursAvail2VM> toursvm = Mapper.Map<IList<Tour>, IList<ToursAvail2VM>>(tours2);
```

**ViewModel:**

```
 public class ToursAvail2VM
 {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int TourCategoryId { get; set; }
    public string TourName { get; set; }
    public int Bookings { get; set; }
 }
```

How do I get the list of results projected onto my toursvm class?

Thanks for any advice, Mark

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your linq query is returning an anonymous type, rather than `Tour`.  You need to explicitly specify the class you would like returned, or AutoMapper can't handle it.

However, since you are using Linq to Entities, you can't specify `ToursAvail2VM` directly.  You can do something like selecting into the anonymous type and then immediately selecting into `ToursAvail2VM` like the following:

```
IList<ToursAvail2VM> toursvm =
                (from vm in
                    (from t in db.Tours
                     join d in db.TourDates on t.TourId equals d.TourId
                     join c in db.TourCategories on t.TourCategoryId equals c.TourCategoryId
                     where d.Date == dte && t.TourCategoryId == id
                     select new
                    {
                        Id = t.TourId,
                        TourName = t.TourName,
                        TourCategoryId = t.TourCategoryId,
                        Bookings = db.Bookings.Where(b => d.TourDateId == b.TourDateId).Count()                            
                    }).ToList()
                select new ToursAvail2VM
                    {
                         Id = vm.Id,
                         TourName = vm.TourName,
                         TourCategoryId = vm.TourCategoryId,
                         Bookings = vm.Bookings
                    }).ToList();
```

Comment: Hi Steve - thanks for the suggestion.  If I add "select new ToursAvail2VM" - it errors when I run it, with the message: The entity or complex type 'tb.Models.ToursAvail2VM' cannot be constructed in a LINQ to Entities query.  That's why I was creating an anonymous type.  Thanks again, Mark

Comment: Ah, I missed the Linq to Entities part.  That always adds a bit of fun.  Updated.

Comment: Hi Steve - thanks for that again.  Unfortunately it still doesn't like it for some reason: `The entity or complex type 'tb.Models.ToursAvail2VM' cannot be constructed in a LINQ to Entities query.`  I'm probably missing something really basic for most others :) Thank you!

Comment: Bah. You need an interim  .ToList () in there I think. I'll take a closer look when I get back to a computer. (On my phone atm.)

Comment: Thanks a lot Steve - I really appreciate your help.  I promise to pay it forward - I help out in some other forums quite a bit :)  Cheers, Mark

Comment: Hang on - I added .ToList just before the select new Tours... and it's working now!!  Brilliant Steve - thanks a lot, I really appreciate it!! Cheers, Mark

Comment: One little thing - I would use AutoMapper's LINQ projection in this case, it gets rid of that Select projection stuff.

Comment: Hi Jimmy - could you send an example of what you mean please?  If there's a better way of optimizing the code using AutoMapper, I'd love to do so.  I listened yesterday to your long interview and screencast you did a few years back - it looks like a great tool - so thank you for that! :) Mark

Comment: Hi Jimmy - it's ok - I found references to it on your LosTechies site - thanks again Jimmy and Steve.

Comment: @JimmyBogard, thanks for pointing me at the LINQ projection in AutoMapper.  My knowledge must be a little out of date. :)  If you add an answer, I'll gladly upvote.

Answer (score 5):

For this example, I'd use AutoMapper's [LINQ projection capabilities](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Queryable-Extensions).

```
// This would be somewhere in initialization
Mapper.CreateMap<Tour, ToursAvail2VM>()
    .ForMember(d => d.Bookings, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => 
        src.TourDates.Sum(td => td.Bookings.Count()));

var toursvm = (from t in db.Tours
                 join d in db.TourDates on t.TourId equals d.TourId
                 join c in db.TourCategories on t.TourCategoryId equals c.TourCategoryId
                 where d.Date == dte && t.TourCategoryId == id
                )
              .Project().To<ToursAvail2VM>()
              .ToList();
```

I'm assuming you include navigation properties in your model here to allow you to navigate from Tour to TourDates to Bookings directly.

Comment: I've got a model without navigation properties (CRM database). So the only thing I end up is always an anonymous type, with properties named by their source table like: new { hrrm, hrec } [human res. record mgmgt, hr employee contact]. Is there an elegant way to use projection with automapper on such return types? Reason is simple: wan't to avoid manual duplicit mapping (others will work on the code too). Thanx.