# Return data from inner join without creating new object

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, entity-framework-core, automapper

I have problem that I`m not able to find solution, what I want is to return data from this query and I also use aspnetboilerplate.

This is my class

```
public  List<Student>  GetStudentWithCityName()
   {
    var a = from s in _studentRepository.GetAll() 
            join c in _cityRepository.GetAll() on s.City_Id equals c.Id
            select new {name = s.Name });
    return ObjectMapper.Map<List<Student>>(a);
   }
```

[image]

With this query I create new object and that`s why don`t work ( at least I think ) so is there any solution to fix this problem ?

Comment: Why even bother with `select new {name = s.Name}` and not select a new `Student`?

Comment: @Llama thank you for quick response , well It`s just for example , ofc that I want to select new student :) , is there any suggestion how to improve this query to work ?

Comment: Maybe [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28611643/automapper-query-for-projecting-an-anonymous-type-onto-a-viewmodel) can help you.

Answer (score 1):

The exception you're getting is from auto mapper's object, telling you, the mapping configuration doesn't exist. You are mapping anonymous type with Student.

Directly select `Student` class. You don't need to map separately. Just replace your select clause with:

```
select new Student
{
   Name = s.Name
}
```

and `return a.ToList();`

Or: You can also use Auto Mapper's LINQ projection, more info here -> https://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Queryable-Extensions.html

Answer (score 0):

Apparently you have a table of `Cities` and a table of `Students`. Every Student has at least a `Name`, and a `CityId`, which is the foreign key to the City that he lives in.

Now give a string `name`, you want all Students that have a value for property `Name` that equals this name, together with the City of this Student.

I'll do this in baby steps, so you can see what happens. Because LINQ uses deferred execution, this won't slow down your process. Of course you can put it all together in one big LINQ statement. Although this won't improve efficiency very much, I'm sure it will deteriorate readability.

```
string name = ...;

IQueryable<City> allCities = _cityRepository.GetAll();
IQueryable<Student> allStudents = _studentRepository.GetAll();

// keep only the zero or more Students with name:
IQueryable<Student> studentsWithName = allStudents
    .Where(student => student.Name == name);

// combine the Student with the City:
var studentsWithCity = studentsWithName.Join(allCities,

    student => student.CityId,     // from every Student take the foreign key
    city => city.Id,               // from every City take the primary key

    // parameter resultSelector: take he student with his matching city to make one new:
    (student, cityOfThisStudent) => new
    {
         // select only the Student properties that you plan to use
         StudentId = student.Id,
         Name = student.Name,
         DateOfBirth = student.BirthDay,

         // select only the City properties that you plan to use:
         City = cityOfThisStudent.Name,
         ...
    });
```

If your `GetAll` methods return `IQueryable<...>`, the query is intended to be executed by an external process (usually a database management system). This DBMS is way more optimized to combine tables, sort data and select properties than your local process. My advice would be to keep your query an IQueryable as long as possible. Disadvantage: you can't use your local methods for this.

If `GetAll` returns an `IEnumerable<...>`, than your local process has to do the `Where` and the `Join`. In that case you can use the ObjectMapper:

```
// parameter resultSelector:
(student, cityOfThisStudent) => ObjectMapper.Map(...));
```

The LINQ methods for Iqueryable and IEnumerable are very similar. IEnumerable however gives you more freedom to use your own methods at a possible cost of efficiency.

> If every item has exactly one item from another table, like Order with its one and only Customer, or Student with the one and only School he attends, or in your case: Student with the one and only City he lives in, consider to use `Join`. If you want to select items with their zero or more other items, like Schools with their Students, Customers with their orders, etc consider to use GroupJoin.

GroupJoin is very similar to Join, only parameter resultSelector is different.

```
var CustomersWithTheirNonPaidOrders = dbContext.Customers.GroupJoin(
    dbContext.Orders,
    customer => customer.Id,      // from every Customer take the primary key
    order => order.CustomerId,    // from every Order take the foreign key

    // resultSelector: for every Customer with its zero or more Orders, make one new:
    (customer, OrdersOfThisCustomer) => new
    {
        // Select only the Properties of Customer that you plan to use:
        Id = customer.Id,
        Name = customer.Name,
        ...

        NonPaidOrders = OrdersOfThisCustomer
            .Where(order => !order.IsPaid)
            .Select(order => new
            {
                Date = order.Date,
                Total = order.Total,
                ...
            })
            .ToList(),
});
```